# Comparar expresión regular de un atributo HTML y el input en una condicional if

Tags: javascript, regex, condiciones, arraylist, setattribute

Tengo un input para ingresar número de teléfono en un formulario.

Los datos traigo desde una lista array, y escribo en una lista `ul`, solo en el `activo`, y en un atributo.

Desde este atributo `data-regular` (en la lista `ul`) tomo la expresión regular para comparar el número telefónico si es correcto o no.

De esta forma intento traer la expresión regular:

```
let activo = document.querySelector("#userSelect-opciones .opcion.activo");
let estes = activo.getAttribute("data-regular");

if(estes.match(inputUs.value)) {
    
    numeroUser.style.color = "green";
    console.log("CORRECTO")

} else {
    numeroUser.style.color = "brown";
}

infos.classList.add("visible");
```

};

Lo que quiero hacer y no logro hacer con `estes.match(inputUs.value)` es comparar la cantidad de número del país con el `input.value` e indicar el número (en el HTML) en color verde. O si no, en rojo.

¿Por qué la condicional no toma nada desde el atributo en HTML ?

También intenté con `.test()` sin resultados.
Y también de muchas otras formas sin lograr.

Pero si ingreso la expresión regular directamente en la condicional `if` si funciona, pero sería para un solo país y los demás no servirían:

```
if(/^([0-9]{10})$/.test(inputUs.value))
```

Éste es mi formulario resumido al máximo para el demo perfecto:

```js
const inputUserTel = document.getElementById("inputUserTel");
const estes = document.getElementById("grupoForm-inputUserTel");
const infos = estes.querySelector(".infoTel");
const userOpciones = document.getElementById("userSelect-opciones");

const datos = {
Argentina: {
    pais: "Argentina",
    codigo: "+54",
    regular: /^([0-9]{10})$/,
    value: "0000 000 000",
    bandera: "src/banderas/ar.png",
},
Brazil: {
    pais: "Brazil",
    codigo: "+55",
    regular: /^([0-9]{3})$/,
    value: "00 0000 000",
    bandera: "src/banderas/br.png"
},
Paraguay: {
    pais: "Paraguay",
    codigo: "+595",
    value: "000 000 000",
    regular: /^([0-9]{10})$/,
    bandera: "src/banderas/py.png" 
},
};

let opciones = "";

for (let i in datos) {
opciones += `
    <li class="opcion" data="${datos[i].pais}" data-value="${datos[i].value}" data-regular="${datos[i].regular}" data-codigo="${datos[i].codigo}">
        <img src="${datos[i].bandera}">
        <span style="margin-right:3px">${datos[i].pais}:</span> (${datos[i].codigo})
    </li>
`
} userOpciones.innerHTML += opciones;

function usuarioSelect() {

userOpciones.classList.toggle("activo");

if(userOpciones.classList.contains("activo")) {
    
    document.addEventListener("click", function() {
        yoDesseleccion();
    },{once:true, capture:true});

    userOpciones.addEventListener("mouseleave", yoDesseleccion);
    
} else yoDesseleccion();

function yoDesseleccion() {
    userOpciones.classList.remove("activo");
};
};

document.querySelectorAll("#userSelect-opciones .opcion").forEach( (e) => {

e.addEventListener("mouseenter", (ev) => { 
    let active = userOpciones.querySelector(".opcion.activo");
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
    active = ev.target;
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
});

e.addEventListener("click", yoSelectCódigo);
});

function yoSelectCódigo() {

const selecto = document.getElementById("userSelect-selecto");
const act = userOpciones.querySelector(".opcion.activo"); 
const ape = document.querySelector(".paisUser");

if(window.event.key == "Enter") evento();
else evento();

function evento() {
    
    const place = act.getAttribute("data");
    const codigo = act.getAttribute("data-codigo");
    const plas = act.getAttribute("data-value");
    
    inputUserTel.setAttribute("placeholder", plas);
    ape.innerHTML = place + ": " + codigo;
    selecto.innerHTML = act.innerHTML;
    infos.classList.add("visible");
    inputUserTel.focus();
};

userOpciones.classList.remove("activo");
};

function userTel(ev) {

const numeroUser = infos.querySelector(".numeroUser");
const inputUs = document.getElementById("inputUserTel");

let activo = document.querySelector("#userSelect-opciones .opcion.activo");
let estes = activo.getAttribute("data-regular");

numeroUser.innerHTML = ev.value;

if(estes.match(inputUs.value)) {
    
    numeroUser.style.color = "green";
    console.log("CORRECTO")

} else {
    numeroUser.style.color = "brown";
}

infos.classList.add("visible");
};

inputUserTel.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => userTel(e.target));
userSelect.addEventListener("click", usuarioSelect);
userSelect.addEventListener("focusin", usuarioSelect);
userSelect.addEventListener("focusout", usuarioSelect);

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {

const us = document.getElementById("userSelect-opciones");

let activo = us.classList.contains("activo");
let active = document.querySelector(".opcion.activo");
  
if(e.key == "ArrowUp" && activo) {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
    active = active.previousElementSibling || active.parentNode.lastElementChild;
    active.classList.toggle("activo");

} else if(e.key == "ArrowDown" && activo) {

    e.preventDefault();
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
    active = active.nextElementSibling || active.parentNode.firstElementChild
    active.classList.toggle("activo");

} else if(e.key == "Enter" && activo) yoSelectCódigo();
});
```

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box
}

.formUser {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 350px;
height: 100%;
padding: .50rem;
background-color: silver;
backdrop-filter: blur(3px)
}

.grupoForm {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 5px 5px;
color: grey;
border: 1.5px solid grey;
border-radius: .25rem;
background: transparent;
backdrop-filter: blur(5px)
} .grupoForm.error {
border-color: var(--marron)
} .grupoForm.correcto {
border-color: var(--verde)
} .grupoForm.correctoAmarillo {
border-color: var(--naranja)
}

#userSelect, .userSelect-selecto {
width: fit-content
} .userSelect-selecto {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
white-space: nowrap
} .userSelect-opciones {
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
bottom: 100%;
left: 0;
max-width: 185px;
max-height: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-radius: .20rem;
overflow-y: auto;
background: grey;
backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out
} .userSelect-opciones.activo {
max-height: 300px
} .userSelect-selecto span {
display: none
} .userSelect-opciones .opcion {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
white-space: nowrap;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding: .30rem .30rem;
margin-bottom: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: .7rem;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff
} .userSelect-selecto img, .userSelect-opciones .opcion img {
width: 25px;
height: 15px;
object-fit: cover;
margin-right: 5px
} .userSelect-opciones .opcion img, .userSelect-opciones .opcion span {
pointer-events: none
} .userSelect-opciones .opcion.activo {
color: blue;
background-color: lightblue
}

.btn-group input[type="tel"] {
text-align: left;
width: 100%
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>

<form id="formUser" class="formUser">
    
    
    
    <fieldset id="grupoForm-inputUserTel" class="grupoForm inputUserTel" style="margin-top:100px">
        <legend>Número de teléfono</legend>
        <div id="grupo-selecto" class="btn-group mb-3">

            <span class="btn btn-secondary bi-hash"></span>

            <button type="button" id="userSelect" class="btn btn-secondary">
                <span id="userSelect-selecto" class="userSelect-selecto">Seleccionar</span>
            </button>
            
            <ul id="userSelect-opciones" class="userSelect-opciones" tabindex="-1">
                <li class="opcion activo">Seleccionar</li>
            </ul>

            <input type="tel" class="btn btn-secondary" id="inputUserTel" class="btn btn-secondary" name="inputUserTel" placeholder="Número..." required>
        </div>

        <div class="infoTel" id="formularioInfoTel">
            <span class="paisUser"></span><span class="numeroUser"></span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

</form>


<script src="form.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saludos a [RobertoLeOr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/177464/robertoleor) y a [infinit3Loop__](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/224775/infinit3loop) por la respuesta y la solución. Los dos merecen aceptar pero es difícil decidir

Comment: Dato menor: los números de teléfono móvil de Paraguay son con 10 dígitos (si se reemplaza el código de área por "0", con el formato "0000 000 000"). Por lo tanto, al value en los datos le falta un cero :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De manera general:

- las funciones dentro de funciones las puse al mismo nivel de las demás.
- Cada **regular** se paso a cadena; ya que al asignarlo al elemento es más fácil usarlo. Solo **Argentina** realice corrección; en tu formato indicas espacios. *Te queda completar bien las demas*
- Tu función *yoSelectCódigo* la deje como **yoSelectCodigo** (quite acento).
- Tu función **userTel** ahí coloque comentarios de cambios.

*Espero no me falte nada por indicar cambie*

```js
const inputUserTel = document.getElementById("inputUserTel");
const estes = document.getElementById("grupoForm-inputUserTel");
const infos = estes.querySelector(".infoTel");
const userOpciones = document.getElementById("userSelect-opciones");

const datos = {
Argentina: {
    pais: "Argentina",
    codigo: "+54",
    regular: "^[0-9]{4}[\\s]{1}[0-9]{3}[\\s]{1}[0-9]{3}$",
    value: "0000 000 000",
    bandera: "src/banderas/ar.png",
},
Brazil: {
    pais: "Brazil",
    codigo: "+55",
    regular: "^([0-9]{3})$",
    value: "00 0000 000",
    bandera: "src/banderas/br.png"
},
Paraguay: {
    pais: "Paraguay",
    codigo: "+595",
    value: "000 000 000",
    regular: "^([0-9]{10})$",
    bandera: "src/banderas/py.png" 
},
};

let opciones = "";

for (let i in datos) {
opciones += `
    <li class="opcion" data="${datos[i].pais}" data-value="${datos[i].value}" data-regular="${datos[i].regular}" data-codigo="${datos[i].codigo}">
        <img src="${datos[i].bandera}">
        <span style="margin-right:3px">${datos[i].pais}:</span> (${datos[i].codigo})
    </li>
`
}
userOpciones.innerHTML += opciones;

function usuarioSelect() {

    userOpciones.classList.toggle("activo");

    if(userOpciones.classList.contains("activo")) {
    
        document.addEventListener("click", function() {
            yoDesseleccion();
        },{once:true, capture:true});

        userOpciones.addEventListener("mouseleave", yoDesseleccion);
    
    } else yoDesseleccion();

};

function yoDesseleccion() {
    userOpciones.classList.remove("activo");
};

document.querySelectorAll("#userSelect-opciones .opcion").forEach( (e) => {

    e.addEventListener("mouseenter", (ev) => { 
        let active = userOpciones.querySelector(".opcion.activo");
        active.classList.toggle("activo");
        active = ev.target;
        active.classList.toggle("activo");
    });

    e.addEventListener("click", yoSelectCodigo);
});

function evento() {
    const selecto = document.getElementById("userSelect-selecto");
    const act = userOpciones.querySelector(".opcion.activo"); 
    const ape = document.querySelector(".paisUser");
 
    const place = act.getAttribute("data");
    const codigo = act.getAttribute("data-codigo");
    const plas = act.getAttribute("data-value");
    
    inputUserTel.setAttribute("placeholder", plas);
    ape.innerHTML = place + ": " + codigo;
    selecto.innerHTML = act.innerHTML;
    infos.classList.add("visible");
    inputUserTel.focus();
};

function yoSelectCodigo() {


    if(window.event.key == "Enter") evento();
    else evento();


    userOpciones.classList.remove("activo");
};

function userTel(ev) {
    // Cambio a document el infos
    let numeroUser = document.querySelector(".numeroUser");
    const inputUs = document.getElementById("inputUserTel");

    let activo = document.querySelector("#userSelect-opciones .opcion.activo");

    /*
    Cambio de: activo.getAttribute("data-regular")
    A: new RegExp(activo.getAttribute("data-regular"))
    */
    let estes = new RegExp(activo.getAttribute("data-regular"));

    numeroUser.innerHTML = ev.value;

    if(estes.test(ev.value)) {
    
        numeroUser.style.color = "green";
    } else {
        numeroUser.style.color = "brown";
    }

    infos.classList.add("visible");
};

inputUserTel.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => userTel(e.target));
userSelect.addEventListener("click", usuarioSelect);
userSelect.addEventListener("focusin", usuarioSelect);
userSelect.addEventListener("focusout", usuarioSelect);

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {

    const us = document.getElementById("userSelect-opciones");

    let activo = us.classList.contains("activo");
    let active = document.querySelector(".opcion.activo");
  
    if(e.key == "ArrowUp" && activo) {
    
        e.preventDefault();
        active.classList.toggle("activo");
        active = active.previousElementSibling || active.parentNode.lastElementChild;
        active.classList.toggle("activo");

    } else if(e.key == "ArrowDown" && activo) {

        e.preventDefault();
        active.classList.toggle("activo");
        active = active.nextElementSibling || active.parentNode.firstElementChild
        active.classList.toggle("activo");

    } else if(e.key == "Enter" && activo) yoSelectCodigo();
});
```

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box
}

.formUser {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 350px;
height: 100%;
padding: .50rem;
background-color: silver;
backdrop-filter: blur(3px)
}

.grupoForm {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 5px 5px;
color: grey;
border: 1.5px solid grey;
border-radius: .25rem;
background: transparent;
backdrop-filter: blur(5px)
} .grupoForm.error {
border-color: var(--marron)
} .grupoForm.correcto {
border-color: var(--verde)
} .grupoForm.correctoAmarillo {
border-color: var(--naranja)
}

#userSelect, .userSelect-selecto {
width: fit-content
} .userSelect-selecto {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
white-space: nowrap
} .userSelect-opciones {
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
bottom: 100%;
left: 0;
max-width: 185px;
max-height: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-radius: .20rem;
overflow-y: auto;
background: grey;
backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out
} .userSelect-opciones.activo {
max-height: 300px
} .userSelect-selecto span {
display: none
} .userSelect-opciones .opcion {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
white-space: nowrap;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding: .30rem .30rem;
margin-bottom: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: .7rem;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff
} .userSelect-selecto img, .userSelect-opciones .opcion img {
width: 25px;
height: 15px;
object-fit: cover;
margin-right: 5px
} .userSelect-opciones .opcion img, .userSelect-opciones .opcion span {
pointer-events: none
} .userSelect-opciones .opcion.activo {
color: blue;
background-color: lightblue
}

.btn-group input[type="tel"] {
text-align: left;
width: 100%
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>

<form id="formUser" class="formUser">
    
    
    
    <fieldset id="grupoForm-inputUserTel" class="grupoForm inputUserTel" style="margin-top:100px">
        <legend>Número de teléfono</legend>
        <div id="grupo-selecto" class="btn-group mb-3">

            <span class="btn btn-secondary bi-hash"></span>

            <button type="button" id="userSelect" class="btn btn-secondary">
                <span id="userSelect-selecto" class="userSelect-selecto">Seleccionar</span>
            </button>
            
            <ul id="userSelect-opciones" class="userSelect-opciones" tabindex="-1">
                <li class="opcion activo">Seleccionar</li>
            </ul>

            <input type="tel" class="btn btn-secondary" id="inputUserTel" class="btn btn-secondary" name="inputUserTel" placeholder="Número..." required>
        </div>

        <div class="infoTel" id="formularioInfoTel">
            <span class="paisUser"></span><span class="numeroUser"></span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

</form>


<script src="form.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Y, afectaría en algo una función dentro de otra función? Exepto de no poder reutilizar

Comment: Saludos @NarcisoAifuz; solo por el contexto de su declaración y por consiguiente "su existencia"; es como una variable local. si la quieres invocar fuera de la función donde la declaras te marcara error.

Answer (score 2):

El problema del Regex es sencillo, la propiedad 'regular' del arreglo pásala a string y quítale los caracter / inicial y final:

```
regular: "^([0-9]{10})$"
```

Después **userTel** quedaría así:

```
function userTel(ev) {
  const numeroUser = infos.querySelector(".numeroUser");
  const inputUs = document.getElementById("inputUserTel");

  let activo = document.querySelector(".opcion.activo");
  let estes = activo.getAttribute("data-regular");
  estes = new RegExp(estes);

  numeroUser.innerHTML = ev.value;

  if (estes.test(inputUs.value)) numeroUser.style.color = "green";
  else numeroUser.style.color = "brown";

  infos.classList.add("visible");
}
```

Pero aun así tienes un problema que es muy difícil de detectar, has notado que cuando usas el mouse para seleccionar el país luego a la hora de comprobar el numero no funciona bien la mayoría de las veces? esto solo ocurre con el mouse, y es porque estas usando *hover* en cada opcion para aplicar la clase *active*.

Cuando clickeas una opción y el contenedor de opciones hace su animación para cerrarse, el evento hover sigue existiendo en las opciones y lo que hace al moverse el contenedor es pasar encima del cursor, cambiando la clase 'active' sin que nos demos cuenta.

La solución es crear los eventos *hover* al abrir el menu de opciones, y eliminarlos justo cuando se clickea una de las opciones. Para eliminar eventos, la función que maneja el evento *hover* ya no puede ser anónima porque necesitamos llamarla para eliminarla de los eventos.
El código completo:

```js
const inputUserTel = document.getElementById("inputUserTel");
const estes = document.getElementById("grupoForm-inputUserTel");
const infos = estes.querySelector(".infoTel");
const userOpciones = document.getElementById("userSelect-opciones");

const datos = {
  Argentina: {
    pais: "Argentina",
    codigo: "+54",
    regular: "^([0-9]{10})$",
    value: "0000 000 000",
    bandera: "src/banderas/ar.png",
  },
  Brazil: {
    pais: "Brazil",
    codigo: "+55",
    regular: "^([0-9]{3})$",
    value: "00 0000 000",
    bandera: "src/banderas/br.png",
  },
  Paraguay: {
    pais: "Paraguay",
    codigo: "+595",
    value: "000 000 000",
    regular: "^([0-9]{10})$",
    bandera: "src/banderas/py.png",
  },
};

let opciones = "";

for (let i in datos) {
  opciones += `
    <li class="opcion" data="${datos[i].pais}" data-value="${datos[i].value}" data-regular="${datos[i].regular}" data-codigo="${datos[i].codigo}">
        <img src="${datos[i].bandera}">
        <span style="margin-right:3px">${datos[i].pais}:</span> (${datos[i].codigo})
    </li>
`;
}

userOpciones.innerHTML += opciones;

function usuarioSelect() {
  userOpciones.classList.toggle("activo");

  if (userOpciones.classList.contains("activo")) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".opcion").forEach((e) => {
      e.addEventListener("mouseenter", optionMouseEnter);
      e.addEventListener("click", yoSelectCódigo);
    });
    document.addEventListener(
      "click",
      function (e) {
        yoDesseleccion();
      },
      { once: true, capture: true }
    );
  } else yoDesseleccion();

  function yoDesseleccion() {
    userOpciones.classList.remove("activo");
    document.querySelectorAll(".opcion").forEach((e) => {
      e.removeEventListener("mouseenter", optionMouseEnter);
    });
  }
}

function optionMouseEnter(ev) {
  let active = userOpciones.querySelector(".opcion.activo");
  active.classList.toggle("activo");
  active = ev.target;
  active.classList.toggle("activo");
}

function yoSelectCódigo() {
  const selecto = document.getElementById("userSelect-selecto");
  const act = userOpciones.querySelector(".opcion.activo");
  const ape = document.querySelector(".paisUser");

  evento();

  function evento() {
    const place = act.getAttribute("data");
    const codigo = act.getAttribute("data-codigo");
    const plas = act.getAttribute("data-value");

    inputUserTel.setAttribute("placeholder", plas);
    ape.innerHTML = place + ": " + codigo;
    selecto.innerHTML = act.innerHTML;
    infos.classList.add("visible");
    inputUserTel.focus();
  }

  userOpciones.classList.remove("activo");
}

function userTel(ev) {
  const numeroUser = infos.querySelector(".numeroUser");
  const inputUs = document.getElementById("inputUserTel");

  let activo = document.querySelector(".opcion.activo");
  let estes = activo.getAttribute("data-regular");
  estes = new RegExp(estes);

  numeroUser.innerHTML = ev.value;

  if (estes.test(inputUs.value)) numeroUser.style.color = "green";
  else numeroUser.style.color = "brown";

  infos.classList.add("visible");
}

inputUserTel.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => userTel(e.target));
userSelect.addEventListener("click", usuarioSelect);
userSelect.addEventListener("focusin", usuarioSelect);

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  const us = document.getElementById("userSelect-opciones");

  let activo = us.classList.contains("activo");
  let active = document.querySelector(".opcion.activo");

  if (e.key == "ArrowUp" && activo) {
    e.preventDefault();
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
    active =
      active.previousElementSibling || active.parentNode.lastElementChild;
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
  } else if (e.key == "ArrowDown" && activo) {
    e.preventDefault();
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
    active = active.nextElementSibling || active.parentNode.firstElementChild;
    active.classList.toggle("activo");
  } else if (e.key == "Enter" && activo) yoSelectCódigo();
});
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.formUser {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: .50rem;
  background-color: silver;
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px)
}

.grupoForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  color: grey;
  border: 1.5px solid grey;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  background: transparent;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px)
}

.grupoForm.error {
  border-color: var(--marron)
}

.grupoForm.correcto {
  border-color: var(--verde)
}

.grupoForm.correctoAmarillo {
  border-color: var(--naranja)
}

#userSelect,
.userSelect-selecto {
  width: fit-content
}

.userSelect-selecto {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.userSelect-opciones {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 185px;
  max-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: .20rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: grey;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out
}

.userSelect-opciones.activo {
  max-height: 300px
}

.userSelect-selecto span {
  display: none
}

.userSelect-opciones .opcion {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .30rem .30rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .7rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff
}

.userSelect-selecto img,
.userSelect-opciones .opcion img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 15px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-right: 5px
}

.userSelect-opciones .opcion img,
.userSelect-opciones .opcion span {
  pointer-events: none
}

.userSelect-opciones .opcion.activo {
  color: blue;
  background-color: lightblue
}

.btn-group input[type="tel"] {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="formUser" class="formUser">
    <fieldset id="grupoForm-inputUserTel" class="grupoForm inputUserTel" style="margin-top:100px">
      <legend>Número de teléfono</legend>
      <div id="grupo-selecto" class="btn-group mb-3">
        <span class="btn btn-secondary bi-hash"></span>
        <button type="button" id="userSelect" class="btn btn-secondary">
          <span id="userSelect-selecto" class="userSelect-selecto">Seleccionar</span>
        </button>
        <ul id="userSelect-opciones" class="userSelect-opciones" tabindex="-1">
          <li class="opcion activo">Seleccionar</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="tel" class="btn btn-secondary" id="inputUserTel" class="btn btn-secondary" name="inputUserTel"
          placeholder="Número..." required>
      </div>
      <div class="infoTel" id="formularioInfoTel">
        <span class="paisUser"></span><span class="numeroUser"></span>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script src="scripts2.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Estuve literalmente horas encontrando ese error.

Comment: Gracias por arreglar el tema mouseover. Nunca me di cuenta de eso